# SQL query to copy from some columns of a table to one column in another table

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have this scenario

Table 01

```
reportID | response1 | response2 | response3 | response4 | response5
1        | aaa       | bbb       | ccc       | ddd       | eee
2        | fff       | ggg       | hhh       | iii       | jjj
3        | lll       | mmm       | nnn       | ooo       | ppp
...
```

And I would like to insert this data into `table 02`, the result should look like this

```
id | reportID | response
1  | 1        | aaa
2  | 1        | bbb
3  | 1        | ccc
4  | 1        | ddd
5  | 1        | eee
6  | 2        | fff
7  | 2        | ggg
8  | 2        | hhh
9  | 2        | iii
10 | 2        | jjj
11 | 3        | lll
...
```

How can I achieve this, I tried:

```
INSERT INTO table02 (reported, response) 
SELECT reportid, reponse1 FROM table01
```

But it don't seems right.

`Table 01` contains around 4k rows, So the `table 2` will have around 20k.

What is the best approach here.

I could create a console application and do it from there, However I would like to do it from SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid several scans to the table that happen with union all approach, you can also use unpivot to do this:

```
SELECT
  row_number() over (order by (select null)) as id,
  reportID, 
  response
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      reportID, 
      response1, 
      response2, 
      response3, 
      response4, 
      response5
   FROM data) d
UNPIVOT
   (response FOR respId IN 
      (response1, response2, response3, response4, response5)
)AS unpvt;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9ea669

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way is to use `union all`:

```
insert into table02(reported, response)
    select reportid, reponse1 from table01 union all
    select reportid, reponse2 from table01 union all
    select reportid, reponse3 from table01 union all
    select reportid, reponse4 from table01 union all
    select reportid, reponse5 from table01;
```

Comment: Hi, Can you please explain why union all is required here?

Comment: @Clouds Because reponse*n* and reponse*m* might be equal to same reportid (FYI, `UNION ALL` is faster than `UNION`; no duplication check is required)

Comment: You could also use five separate `insert` statements.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SELECT INTO`. See for **[instance](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp)**.

Answer (score 0):

When we need to convert columns data into rows, it is called *UnPivoting* and SQL Server provides a solution for this:

```
SELECT
  row_number() over (order by (select null)) as id,
  reportID, 
  response
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      reportID, 
      response1, 
      response2, 
      response3, 
      response4, 
      response5
   FROM data) d
UNPIVOT
   (response FOR respId IN 
      (response1, response2, response3, response4, response5)
)AS unpvt;
```

Use this query instead of using `Union All`.